# Bucket filling in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on drawing app, which needs bucket filling also.
Any idea on how to perform bucket filling in Flutter?

[image]

Comment: Did you achieve this ?

Comment: yes,it works.But it is inefficient since it takes about 1 minute for filling a 4-inch screen. @EktaPadaliya

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: I will attach the github link here @Ekta Padaliya

Answer (score 4):

You would have to write your own algorithm. I think you could port [this one](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/) to dart.

One fundamental you need is how to get color of a pixel of an image:

```
Color getPixelColor(ByteData rgbaImageData, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int x, int y) {
  assert(x >= 0 && x < imageWidth);
  assert(y >= 0 && y < imageHeight);

  final byteOffset = x * 4 + y * imageWidth * 4;

  final r = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset);
  final g = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset + 1);
  final b = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset + 2);
  final a = rgbaImageData.getUint8(byteOffset + 3);

  return Color.fromARGB(a, r, g, b);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Image image = ...;

final rgbaImageData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);

print(getPixelColor(rgbaImageData, image.width, image.height, x, y));
```

Manipulating it follows the same scheme (`setUint8`).

Comment: thanks,but how can i reflect the changes back to widget?  @boformer

Comment: You have to find a way to create a memory image from the raw bytes, then display it in an `Image` widget. This is clearly not for beginners. You have to know what you are doing

Comment: this function getPixelColor is taking longer time to execute.so that it takes time for bucket filling in even a small area.@boformer

Answer (score 1):

I have written a performant solution for [my app](https://mooltik.app/). It is a [C++ function](https://github.com/ruskakimov/mooltik/blob/master/image_library/flood_fill.cpp) that's called from the dart side with `dart:ffi`. The algorithm is an optimized scanline fill.

It takes around **14ms** to fill an empty `1280x720` image. **10-20ms** for other various shapes. You can take a look at a [full performance breakdown](https://github.com/ruskakimov/mooltik/pull/201). *(Tested in release mode on Xiaomi Mi9)*

The code has been tested in production and users seem to be reasonably happy with it. *(5k active users)*

### Setup:

1. Drop [`image_library`](https://github.com/ruskakimov/mooltik/tree/master/image_library) folder with the C++ source code into the root of your project
2. Insert this into `android` block inside your `android/app/build.gradle` file. Here is my [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/ruskakimov/mooltik/blob/8ab4e75671eacb679a6d4f4f0f2bf0f484eae7fa/android/app/build.gradle) for reference.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "../../image_library/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

3. Create an [ffi bridge](https://github.com/ruskakimov/mooltik/blob/8ab4e75671eacb679a6d4f4f0f2bf0f484eae7fa/lib/ffi_bridge.dart) for convenience. Basically a wrapper around `dart:ffi` to locate your compiled library and some conversions from native dart types into dart:ffi types.
4. Another [wrapper function](https://github.com/ruskakimov/mooltik/blob/8ab4e75671eacb679a6d4f4f0f2bf0f484eae7fa/lib/common/data/flood_fill.dart) that runs the code in an isolate.

The final function has the following interface:

```dart
Future<ui.Image?> floodFill(
  ui.Image source,
  int startX,
  int startY,
  ui.Color color,
)
```

It returns `null` if flood fill has been aborted. This happens if the pixel where the fill has started from has the same color as you are trying to fill.