# Bucket filling in flutter drawing app is too slow

Tags: dart, flutter

the given ideas in  [Bucket filling in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038055/bucket-filling-in-flutter)  is working but its too slow, it takes more time with respect to more pixels. is there any other way to do bucket filling in flutter.